# Inverse spectral theorem, clarification from a video.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I'm following some of the lectures of professor Schuller. I'm watching 
[this video](https://youtu.be/IIF8XfMda4k?t=20m34s) specifically

At about minute 23 he defines the PVM (Projected Valued Measure) as a map

$$
P_A : \sigma(\Theta_\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})
$$

with the specific expression

$$
\langle\psi,P_A(\Omega)\phi\rangle=\int \chi_\Omega d\mu_{\psi,\phi}^A \;\;\forall\psi, \phi \in \mathcal{H}
$$

Here $\mathcal{H}$ is an hilbert space, $A$ is a self-adjoint operator in $\mathcal{H}$, while $\mu_{\psi,\phi}^A$ is a complex valued measure constructed by polarization of a real valued measure $\mu_{\phi}^A$ (these concepts are expressed a bit earlier in the same lecture, but all the constructions are given later).

My question is why the PVM defined above does represent an operator when evaluated in a measurable set? suppose indeed a self-adjoint operator $A$ is given, and we also fix a measurable set $\Omega$, the PVM seems to me to take two arguments and not just one.

Schuller also says that the map is somehow given by that expression, so there's probably something I'm missing.

Can you help me in interpreting that expression?

**Update:**

I've watched the whole video, and I guess my question may be explained as follows. Suppose we are in a vector space of dimension $n$ embedded with a dot product. The dot product is characterized by a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. We can recover such matrix by knowing how the dot product acts on a basis. By taking the canonical base $V = \left\{e_1,\ldots,e_n \right\}$ (columns vectors), we can recover the element $a_{ij}$ as

$$
\langle e_i,e_j \rangle = e_i^T  A  e_j = a_{ij}
$$

If the base is not the canonical one we can perform a transformation and still retrieving the matrix (which again is actually an operator). Hence for *finite* dimension the dot product is fully characterized once we now how it acts on a basis. (I haven't been very precise, but you've got my point I hope).

The expression

$$
\langle\psi,P_A(\Omega)\phi\rangle=\int \chi_\Omega d\mu_{\psi,\phi}^A \;\;\forall\psi, \phi \in \mathcal{H}
$$

it seems to me be somehow related, therefore I was wondering if there's any theorem that characterize self-adjoints operator in a similar fashion as matrices and dot products in finite dimensions. Name of a theorem, any reference, or if you could prove it for me would be really useful.

Comment: The notation are unclear to me. Maybe you can relate it to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure#Extensions_of_projection-valued_measures.2C_integrals_and_the_spectral_theorem) and  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus#Spectral_projections) ?

Comment: @reuns What is unclear specifically?

Comment: The RHS. You need to make it clear how it is a (bi)linear operator in $\psi,\phi$. Did you look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure#Extensions_of_projection-valued_measures.2C_integrals_and_the_spectral_theorem) explaining everything ?

Comment: @reuns I still don't understand. $\psi,\phi$ are taken from the same Hilbert space, hence that is the dot product in that space I suppose.  Regarding the link it seems to me the same stuff, namely it seems to me that Schuller in that video proves the theorem in your link.

Comment: If your question is to find an example : For $\phi,\psi \in L^2([0,1])$, define the linear operator $(\pi_{[0,x]} \phi)(y) = \phi(y) 1_{y \in [0,x]}$, take $f \in C^1([0,1]), f(1) = 0$ and define a  linear operator $T_f$ by $\displaystyle\langle T_f \phi, \psi \rangle = -\int_{[0,1]} f'(x) (\int_{[0,x]} \phi(y) \overline{\psi(y)}dy) dx $ $\displaystyle= -\int_{[0,1]} f'(x) \langle \pi_{[0,x]} \phi, \psi \rangle dx  =
\int_{[0,1]} f(x)  d\langle \pi_{[0,x]} \phi, \psi \rangle$
Then $T_f$ is defined by integrating a projection valued measure.

Comment: @reuns , thanks for the example that will be useful. I'll add more details about my question, bear with me please.

Comment: @reuns I hope my update helps in making myself clearer.

Comment: Although I'm starting to think that probably my question is actually answered by the proof of the spectral theorem.

Comment: Yes the objective is to characterize self-adjoint and normal operators in Hilbert spaces, and to prove the spectral theorem. I'm thinking you didn't study the spectral theorem for compact operators, ie. if $T$ is self-adjoint and compact $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ then $T \phi = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \langle \phi, e_n \rangle e_n$ for some orthonormal family $e_n \in L^2$ and $c_n \in \mathbb{R}, c_n\to 0$. [This version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#Spectral_theorem) is obtained from the spectral theorem in finite dimensional vector spaces

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do these theorems actually help in practice? Looking at those lectures, which again I'm able both to follow and understand, I haven't actually seen it in pratice to decompose a self adjoint operator, I can understand now what it means. Unfortunately I can find lecture notes or problems of this professor, but I would help to find some examples where those notions are actually used (I'm not a physicist so I don't I'd be able to follow the applications he provides later).

Comment: I mean it seems to me that most of the theory is for existence purpose only, not for actually computing something. You can use perturbation theory to elaborate a computational model apparently, but it's not something that you can do as you would usually do with matrices.

Comment: If $b(x,y)$ is a complex function of $x,y\in\mathcal{H}$ that is linear in $x$, conjugate linear in $y$, and satisfies $|b(x,y)| \le C\|x\|\|y\|$ for some constant $C$, then $b(x,y)=\langle Bx,y\rangle$ for a unique bounded linear operator $B$ on $\mathcal{H}$. And, $\|B\| \le C$ in this case. If $b(x,x)$ is real for all $x$, then $B=B^*$. You can prove this using the Riesz Representation Theorem.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts can you point to a reference with the proof?

Comment: @user8469759 : I've given you a theorem statement and a proof using the Riesz Representation theorem. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem [Bounded Form Representation]:** *Let $b(x,y)$ be complex function on a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose $b$ is linear in $x$ and conjugate linear in $y$, and further suppose there is a constant $K$ such that $|b(x,y)| \le K\|x\|\|y\|$ for all $x,y\in\mathcal{H}$. Then there is a unique bounded linear operator $B : \mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ such that $b(x,y)=\langle Bx,y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$ for all $x,y\in\mathcal{H}$; furthermore, $B$ is bounded by the same $K$, which is to say that $\|Bx\| \le K\|x\|$ for all $x\in\mathcal{H}$.*

**Proof:** Assuming $b$ is as stated, then, for every fixed $y$, the function $\Phi_{x}(y)=\overline{b(x,y)}$ is a bounded linear functional on $\mathcal{H}$.
By the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists a unique $Bx\in\mathcal{H}$ such that
$$
         \overline{b(x,y)} = \langle y,Bx\rangle_{\mathcal{H}},\;\;\; y\in\mathcal{H}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
                b(x,y) = \langle Bx,y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}},\;\;\; x,y\in\mathcal{H}.
$$
The function $B : \mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ is a linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$. To see why, first consider that the following holds for all $x,x',y\in\mathcal{H}$:
\begin{align}
      \langle Bx+Bx',y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}&=b(x,y)+b(x',y) \\
     &=b(x+x',y) \\
     &=\langle B(x+x'),y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}.
\end{align}
Hence $B(x+x')=Bx+Bx'$ for all $x,x'\in\mathcal{H}$. Similarly, for all $x\in\mathcal{H}$, $y\in\mathcal{H}$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$,
\begin{align}
     \langle B(\alpha x),y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}&=b(\alpha x,y) \\
     &=\alpha b(x,y) \\
     &=\alpha \langle Bx,y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \\
     &=\langle \alpha Bx,y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}.
\end{align}
Hence $B(\alpha x)=\alpha Bx$ holds for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, $x\in\mathcal{H}$. Therefore, $B$ is a linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$. And $B$ is bounded because of the boundedness of $b$:
\begin{align}
         \|Bx\| & =\sup_{\|y\|=1}|\langle Bx,y\rangle| \\
   & = \sup_{\|y\|=1}|b(x,y)| \\
   & \le \sup_{\|y\|=1} K\|x\|\|y\| \\
   & = K\|x\|.\;\; \blacksquare
\end{align}